# How can I stop widgets from re-executing every time I access the logged-in homepage?

Tags: theme-customizer, optimization

I have a few widgets and they're being built-up every time someone accesses their logged-in homepage.

I assume this is so that everything works nicely.

Unfortunately, this is a tremendous performance hog for when you have, say, a page builder and other few things.

In a way, I'd like to do:

`cache_widget('instagram-widget`);`

Where as this would stop my widget from reloading, unless toyed with.

So, unless the context is `customizer\widgets\edit-widget`, simply serve a cached version of it.

How could I even approach it?

Comment: Do you want to cache _any_ widget, or widgets you have developed yourself? To cache any widget, you might want to look at something like https://github.com/Rarst/fragment-cache.

Comment: @swissspidy Amazing. I read on it, but I'd want something that I can do on my own. I'll read the plugin's core and see what it does, but what should I look at?